# Format TextBox for phone number in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a DataGrid in a WPF window. How can I display a phone number string column in the DataGrid in a format of "(999)999-9999"?

The Phone number column in the DataGrid uses a TextBlock in the CellTemplate and a TextBox in the CellEditingTemplate. The phone number is stored as a string with no formating such as "9995551234".

Is it possible to display the phone as:(999)555-1234 and edit it as (999)555-1234?

Comment: Why not put this directly into the model and add a ToFormattedString() or other property which you bind to? You could also use a Converter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `Text="{Binding PhoneNumber, StringFormat={}{0:(###)###-####}}"`

**Edit**

If your `PhoneNumber` property is of type string, then there's not really a lot you can do with `StringFormat` to format it.

In the past when I've wanted to do something like this, I expose a property called `FormattedPhoneNumber` which returns the formatted phone number for display purposes, and the edit box just binds to  plain old unformatted `PhoneNumber`

```
public string FormattedPhoneNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (PhoneNumber == null)
            return string.Empty;

        switch (PhoneNumber.Length)
        { 
            case 7:
                return Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2");
            case 10:
                return Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
            case 11:
                return Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3-$4");
            default:
                return PhoneNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the phone displays as '9995551234'. It does not use the StringFormat. here is my column of the datagrid:                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhoneNumber, StringFormat={}{0:(###)###-####}}" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

Comment: @Jerry Oh I just realized the PhoneNumber is a string, so updated my answer. If that doesn't work for you then you might have to look into building or finding your own `MaskedTextBox` to use

Comment: Yes, this works great! I added a Partial Class and added FormattedPhoneNumber as a public string. So in my DataGrid, I use FormattedPhoneNumber in the Celltemplate and PhoneNumber in the CellEditingTemplate. Works great thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would like to extend what already Rachel has responded. If a phone number is an integer, StringFormat would work just fine. In case a phone number is a string, I found Converter to be quite handy. This removes the need to create additional property for a class.

Here is an example:

```
public class StringToPhoneConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        //retrieve only numbers in case we are dealing with already formatted phone no
        string phoneNo = value.ToString().Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

        switch (phoneNo.Length)
        {
            case 7:
                return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2");
            case 10:
                return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
            case 11:
                return Regex.Replace(phoneNo, @"(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3-$4");
            default:
                return phoneNo;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.PhoneNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource StringToPhoneConverter}}" />
```

Comment: one thing you should add to your comment for the new devs, 
they should add `<core:StringToPhoneConverter x:Key="StringToPhoneConverter"/>` in `<Window.Resources>` were `<core:` is referring to the location of the Converter class we create after we add `xmlns:core="clr-namespace:yourappName.Core"` in the main *Xaml*

Answer (score 2):

after a short google search i found this two links
the second one is in german

WPF – Masked Textbox Behavior
http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/masked-textbox/

Masked TextBox
http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/wpf-masked-textbox-behavior/

hope this helps