# How to automate the format for numbers in wpf textbox

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, textbox, number-formatting

What I want to do is to input number into the textbox and the number will be automatically inserted thousands commas? I have tried to write a algrithm for string, which is only way that I can think about(I'm kinda new for wpf). Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: hello, take a look ar my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085274/format-textbox-for-phone-number-in-wpf

Comment: could you be more clear on 'automatically inserted thousands commas'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In extension of punker76 answer, then you can use the numeric format:

```
Text="{Binding YourProperty, StringFormat=n}"
```

Comment: Works great. How do you control the number of decimal places?  Answer: StringFormat=n0 (or n1, n2, etc)